# telnetlib python read_all() not getting any output (hangs)

Tags: python, python-2.7, telnet, telnetlib

I am trying to telnet into the cisco console server on a given line with my python script using telnetlib

Below I have mention my code:

```
import time
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = "172.30.144.182"
user = raw_input("enter the admin: ")
password = getpass.getpass()

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, "2035")
tn.read_until("E4Q16000001 login: ")
tn.write(user + '\n')

if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

tn.write("get system status\n")
print tn.read_very_eager()

mytext = tn.set_debuglevel(1000)
mytext = tn.read_all()
print mytext

tn.write("exit\n")
```

Issue: Terminal gets hanged after providing the user info and the password.
When I clear the line on the cisco terminal I get the following errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./t1.py", line 15, in <module>tn.read_until("E4Q16000001 login: ")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 294, in read_untilreturnself._read_until_with_poll(match, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 343, in _read_until_with_pollreturn self.read_very_lazy()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/telnetlib.py", line 455, in read_very_lazyraise EOFError, 'telnet connection closed'
```

I believe my script is connecting the console server (end device on line 35) as I get the above error once I clear the line on cisco console server

Methods of approach:

- I tried to use  "tn.write("vt100\n") tn.write("get system status\n")
  but it did not helped
- I tried to set debug level, used read_very_eager but no results
  Please do advice if something is missing, Thanks for your help

Comment: Please check the formatting in your question. the script is difficult to understand without indentation.

Comment: Hello @CoryMadden, thanks for your response I have edited my code with indentation. Please share your comments

Comment: `\n` is not the same as `Return/Enter` key. Try `\r`.

Comment: @User_1 I'm not sure what the problem is. It _looks_ fine based on the Python2 docs for telnetlib, but I've never used it. @alvits the documentation shows to use `\n`.  Look at the bottom of this page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the line `tn.write("get system status")`? What happens if you remove that?

Comment: @CoryMadden - that is interesting considering `\n` is ASCII(10) while `\r` is ASCII(13) which is `cr`. Maybe telnetlib converts it automatically. Thanks for the URL link.

Comment: @User_1 - have you tried manually walking thru to make sure you have the correct prompts? A simple typo error, such as missing a single character in the expected prompt will cause this error you see.

Comment: @CoryMadden thank for the reply: tn.write("get system status") is the CLI command for FortiOS, I am trying to telnet the Fortigate behind my cisco console server

Comment: @alvits thanks for the comment, yes I did walk thru and there is no typo and I am using \n not \r

Comment: Apparently we're all looking at the wrong places. The behavior you are seeing is normal. As stated in the URL that was given by @CoryMadden, _Telnet.read_all() Read all data until EOF; **block until connection closed**._ Hence the appearance that it hangs, cause it was blocking until the connection times out. Try using `read_very_eager()` instead of `read_all()`.

Comment: @alvits, that does _sound_ like the issue, but the last line of his question says "I tried to set debug level, used read_very_eager but no results".

Comment: @CoryMadden - that was tried but the OP failed to remove these lines `mytext = tn.read_all(); print mytext` which would cause it to hang until the connection times out. `exit` is never executed by the session.

Comment: Ah, I see. I just reread the code. I thought he meant he tried them all separately.

Comment: @alvits thanks for helping,  I removed set debug level and using "tn.read_very_eager()" but no results, still stuck in the hang mode. I am pretty sure that code is hitting the console server/device because I have to clear the line on the console to execute my code again (also get the above error mention in the original description)